# $.ajax to $getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to convert following Jquery code to use $.ajax intead of $.getJSON, what will be $.ajax code for this?

```
$(function () {
    $('#checkExists').click(function () {
     $.getJSON($(this).attr('href'), function (result) {
            alert(result);
            if (result) {
                alert('the record exists');
            }           
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Please suggest

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
  url: $(this).attr('href'),
  success: function (result) { ... },
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

Also, I'd suggest using `event.preventDefault()` instead of `return false;`

Comment: It loads on page load and shows alert with text success, I want to show it on link click

Comment: The put the code posted above within the `$('#checkExists').click(function(){ // code here })` block...

Comment: I did like this but same issue :(  $(function () {
    $('#checkExists').click(function () {
           $.ajax({
  url: $(this).attr('href'),
  success: function (result) {alert('I am here'); },
  dataType: 'json'
});
        return false;
    });
});

Comment: @DotnetSparrow, what is the issue that you're having.  Your original post didn't pose any problem, just asked for a translation between the two method calls.  If you're looking for something significantly different, then please post a new question.  Otherwise, edit your original question to clarify what you're looking for.